# Spring MVC - 404 - Not Found on Wildfly server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, wildfly

I've created very simple 'Hello World' maven project using apache webapp artifact. When I run it on Tomcat It run's Ok but I want use Wildfly app server, when I run it on Wildfly 13.Beta, it gives me error - 404 - Not Found. I'm using Java config only, NO web.xml.

[Here is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nlf4.jpg)

**POM.XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.adamek.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>library-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>library-project Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.14.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Embedded Apache Tomcat required for testing war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2.Final</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class Controllers {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getHome(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**SpringConfig**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.library")
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");   }

}
```

**DispatcherInitializer**

```
public class DispatcherInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class [] {SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String [] {"/"};
    }

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check the app server's logs?

Comment: You should compile and build your project in Wildfly app server enviroment ?

Comment: Im using eclipse, I started Wildfly server from servers tab -----> mvn wildfly:deploy ----> then I entered this url to Chrome - `http://localhost:8080/library-project/` it still gives me same error.